# Does an Antimagic Field spell block class features?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

The Antimagic Field spell mentions the following:

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact
>   or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere...

Does this include magical class features?

Example:
A Transmutation Wizard's 6th level feature is the Transmuter's Stone, which mentions:

> Starting at 6th level, you can spend 8 hours creating a transmuter’s
>   stone that stores transmutation magic. You can benefit from the stone
>   yourself or give it to another creature. A creature gains a benefit of
>   your choice as long as the stone is in the creature’s possession.

The Antimagic Field spell has specific mentions about

Magic Items:

> The properties and powers of magic items are suppressed in the sphere.

Object:

> A creature or object summoned or created by magic temporarily winks
>   out of existance in the sphere.

So, if someone holding a Transmuter's Stone finds himself inside an Antimagic Field, does he retain the benefit granted by the stone? Does he temporarily lose it? Does the stone wink out of existance while inside the sphere?

Similarly if you are an Enchantment Wizard, can you use your Hypnotic Gaze?

> Starting at 2nd level when you choose this school, your soft words and
>   enchanting gaze can magically enthrall another creature.

Does an Abjuration wizard's Arcane Ward remain functional within the sphere assuming it was created outside or does it stop working until the wizard leaves the range of the spell?

This question is not only about the above mentioned class features or just wizard features but generally **whether or not an Antimagic Field spell affects class features and if yes, how to determine which ones are affected?**